# I am getting below error while creating multiple custom get request inside single APIview class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My Views.py

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

```
class Sample(APIView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']

    def get(self, request):
        # Your logic for the default GET method
        response_data = {'message': 'Default GET method'}
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def get_fruits(self, request):
        # Your logic for a custom GET method
        fruits = ["apple", "mango", "orange"]
        response_data = {'fruits': fruits}
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def get_films(self, request):
        # Your logic for another custom GET method
        films = ["Saj", "don", "Man"]
        response_data = {"fnames": films}
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Sample
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Apiapp', Sample, basename='Sample')

urlpatterns = [
    path('sample/get_fruits/', Sample.as_view({'get': 'get_fruits'}), name='custom-endpoint-1'),
     path('sample', Sample.as_view(), name='get-fruits'),
     path('sample/films/', Sample.as_view({'get': 'get_films'}), name='get-films'),]
```

[i am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMcUr.png)

Comment: you can't do like this in APIView because default implementation does not support this it only handle one get method. So either you can handle this in one get handler(method) based on condition or  you have to override the dispatch method to do handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `get_fruits` and `get_films` methods in your `Sample` class are not designed to handle the Django REST Framework's style of handling viewsets.

When you use the `DefaultRouter` and `router.register`, it expects the view to be a DRF viewset, which should have methods like `list`, `create`, `update`, `retrieve`, etc., instead of custom methods like `get_fruits` and `get_films`.

To fix this issue, you can either refactor your `Sample` class to be a DRF viewset or modify your URLs to match the current structure.

**Option 1: Refactor Sample as DRF Viewset**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class Sample(viewsets.ViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']

    def list(self, request):
        # Your logic for the default GET method
        response_data = {'message': 'Default GET method'}
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def get_fruits(self, request):
        # Your logic for a custom GET method
        fruits = ["apple", "mango", "orange"]
        response_data = {'fruits': fruits}
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def get_films(self, request):
        # Your logic for another custom GET method
        films = ["Saj", "don", "Man"]
        response_data = {"fnames": films}
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Option 2: Modify URLs**
If you want to keep the current structure, you can modify your URLs like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Sample

urlpatterns = [
    path('sample/', Sample.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='default-endpoint'),
    path('sample/get_fruits/', Sample.as_view({'get': 'get_fruits'}), name='custom-endpoint-1'),
    path('sample/films/', Sample.as_view({'get': 'get_films'}), name='get-films'),
]
```

This way, you map the `get_fruits` method to a separate endpoint, and the default `list` method is mapped to the default endpoint.